# Join Django model from other database

Tags: python, django, object, model

The situation is as follows in the Django implementation:

- Two different database;
- Two models with different information
- Order number is relation between these models.

I would like to join these models together to get related information. Example

```
class CurtainOrder(models.Model):
  order = models.ForeignKey('curtainconfig.Order', related_name='curtains')
  order_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
  order_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ProductionOrder(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'lOrder_id')
    order_number = models.IntegerField(db_column=u'nOrderNumber')
    status = models.TextField(db_column=u'cExternalDescription')
    class Meta:
        app_label = u'backend'
        db_table = u'ORDER'
        database_name = 'production'
```

To get the result by an query would be as follow:

```
SELECT
    co.order_number, co.order_type, po.status
FROM
    CurtainOrder co
INNER JOIN
    [production].dbo.ProductionOrder po on po.order_number = co.order_number
```

But how can I get the same result in Django code?

I have tried to use SQL query in Django, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/, like below:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
sql = """SELECT 
           co.order_number, co.order_type, po.status
         FROM
           CurtainOrder co
         INNER JOIN
           [production].dbo.ProductionOrder po on po.order_number = co.order_number """
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

This is returning the error: return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

It's going wrong when the 'production' db is joined, but the SQL query is executed good by doing it directly in the database management app.

Comment: You need to have two database connections in your settings. Not sure if the ORM takes the database into account when building queries. I would consult the ORM source code.

Comment: Connections are available. Example ProductionOrder.objects.get(order_number=154) and CurtainOrder.objects.get(order_number=154) are working proper.

Comment: I mean in the instance of doing a join between them: e.g. SELECT DB_A.app_table.model, DB_B.app_table.model.

Comment: You can't do it in ORM, django does not support cross-database queries by default. You must use raw query to do that.

Comment: I tried to used SQL query, see the updated question, but it's still not working. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to add in the database name to the query?

Comment: Thx, this is working. Problem was also that the production database is MSSQL en test SQLite. And the syntax is different  between these dbs :-(!